# How interface could extend java.lang.Object?

Tags: java

I have found in `JLS` this paragraph

> If an interface has no direct superinterfaces, then the interface
>   implicitly declares a public abstract member method m with signature
>   s, return type r, and throws clause t corresponding to each public
>   instance method m with signature s, return type r, and throws clause t
>   declared in Object, unless a method with the same signature, same
>   return type, and a compatible throws clause is explicitly declared by
>   the interface.

Does that mean that interface makes some kind of inheritance from Object API?

**UPD**

Why can I call Object's method via interface type?

```
interface I {}

I i = ...

i.toString();
```

I see here some kind of binding. For me it looks like we bind `Object`'s method to `I` type.

Comment: What part of that makes you think there is any inheritance relation between an interface type and the type `Object`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis `the interface implicitly declares...` We do something similar to this in inheritance, isn't it?

Comment: And how does declaring methods create an inheritance relation?

Comment: It is the right question. I don't know. And how does it do that kind of stuff?

Comment: The quote in your question answers the question in your UPD.

Answer (score 2):

It only means that for any variable of any interface type you can execute all of `Object`'s methods. This makes sense, since any implementation of any interface is a sub-class of `Object` (either directly on indirectly), so it has implementations of all of `Object`'s methods.

It doesn't mean that an interface "inherits" from the Object class, since interfaces can only extend other interfaces.

Comment: If so then why I can call `Object's` method via the interface type variable  (see my update)?

Comment: @JohnWinter The answer to that is precisely the quote you posted from the JLS. Each interface either implicitly declares methods with the same signatures as all of Object's methods or inherits such methods from its super interfaces.

Comment: Ok, but why it is not inheritance? I don't get it.

Comment: @JohnWinter I can declare a class `A` with a method `A#someMethod()` and another class `B` with a method also named `someMethod`. There's still no relation between `A` and `B`.